# Copying csv from database into a new table

Tags: postgresql

I understand that postgres can copy a csv file from the filesystem into a table like this:

```
COPY my_table
FROM '/home/xxx/test.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER;
```

I am wondering whether i can load a csv file that is stored as a bytea in another table ?
Maybe something like:

```
COPY my_table
FROM (select my_csv_bytea from my_csv where id = 1)
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No as `bytea` is not `CSV`. You would have to extract the `bytea` field and convert it into its `CSV` form and then you could load it into the table.